# SQL-SERVER: how to get the maximum length of a variable of VARCHAR help

Tags: sql-server

[image: the query that i've tried to do is]

Hello, in this question im trying to get the maximum length of a name but i cnat seem to figure out what im doing wrong, i've search the web for answer but find none. i tried to put the MAX function in the select clause but it didnt seem to fix it, what am i doing wrong?? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing integer to string. You need to compare length of customer name with max of length and not with direct customer name.

You could modify your code as below:

```
SELECT
CustomerName AS LongestName,
LEN(CustomerName) AS LengthOfName,
FROM
MsCustomer
where 
len(CustomerName) = (SELECT MAX(LEN(CustomerName)) from MsCustomer)
```

I am not really sure what are you trying to do with `STATUS = 'Customer'` code.

There are tonnes of article on [web](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php) for finding the record for max of certain things.

Hope this answers your concern.